# What is the maximum efficiency of a mechanical electric generator?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, power, energy-efficiency, power-engineering

If we apply a simple push to rotate a system of gears to generate electricity, what is the maximum practical and theoretical power efficiency of the system, assuming the push as the only source of energy? What if the gears are to be rotated continuously?

Comment: The maximum efficiency will be limited by: generator efficiency, bearing friction losses, gear friction losses and losses due to any other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, we can get arbitrarily close to 100%.

In practice, the higher the efficiency you want, the more the generator will cost.